# Imaplib Select Fails while connecting folder(**Labelname) of gmail

Tags: python, gmail-imap, imaplib

I am using imaplib module for connecting to Gmail Imap, and i am getting the below mentioned error. 
I am using select command to connect

```
Labelname is  **LabelName
```

I Get this Error:

```
    resp, data = self._imap.select("**LabelName")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 642, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 1060, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 895, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']
```

whereas if the Labelname is

```
** LabelName
```

It successfully connects.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here ?

Comment: this error is not there in php library when we try to connect

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue, while connecting using imaplib we need to connect like this:

```
imapobj.select('"'+ '**Foldername' + '"')
```

this results into select like this

```
"**Foldername"
```